# How to find the highest combination while comparing three numbers in php

Tags: php

There are three numbers in set A {3,4,7} and in set B {2,4,7}.

It is not possible to get the result true because the the first numbers in a and b are not same.

But I need to get the result as true by comparing other two number and leaving the first number.

How is it possible to do it in PHP?

Comment: count the differences... if count of differences > 1 then false, else true... for specifics, how are your sets defined? (ie. what datatype?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it will helps you.. it will display the 1 => for more number of combinations as same and  0 => for more of combination as different . in the below code the more number of combination as different so its returns 0.

```
<?php
$A = array(2,3,7,5,6);
$B = array(4,3,7,8,9);

$flagTrue = 0;
$flagFalse = 0;
for($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++)
{
    if($A[$i] == $B[$i])
    {
        $flagTrue=$flagTrue+1;
    }
    else 
    {
        $flagFalse=$flagFalse+1;
    }
}

$var_is_greater_than_two = ($flagTrue >= $flagFalse) ? 1 : 0;
echo $var_is_greater_than_two;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$a = array(3,4,7);
$b = array(2,4,7);

echo $a === $b ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';

echo PHP_EOL;

array_shift($a);
array_shift($b);

echo $a === $b ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
?>
```

Shows:

```
FALSE TRUE
```

**UPD:**

If you need to extract values from strings, then:

```
$strA = '3,4,7';
$strB = '2,4,7';

$a = explode(',', $strA);
$b = explode(',', $strB);

array_shift($a);
array_shift($b);

echo $a === $b ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$A = array(2,3,7);
$B = array(4,3,7);

$isTrue=1;
for($i=1; $i < count($A); $i++) if($A[$i]!=$B[$i]) $isTrue=0;

echo $isTrue;
?>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to return true if exactly two elements are the same, then the code would be:

```
$common=0;
for($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++) if($a[$i]==$b[$i]) $common++;
if($common==2) $isTrue=1;
```

Comment: If I want to check all the number in the array separately by comparing A with B. The above code checks only the first array can you please help me out to check other two and get me the result 1 if any two combinations are true or else 0 .

Comment: @SingiFizz: I do not understand your second request. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MKG: I agree, but this code is my understanding of the problem (and its generalization). Would the problem be extended in order to get 1 if two values are in common, then my code would not be appropriate anymore.

Comment: If the sets A was (2,3,7) and B was (2,4,7) . the code above showed me result as 0 but i need the result to be 1 .because i must get true if there is any 2 common values. please help me with it .

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969837/how-to-find-the-highest-combination-while-comparing-three-numbers-in-php/15970902#15970902

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareSets($a, $b) {
    $result = TRUE;
    $diffArray = array_diff($a, $b);
    foreach ($diffArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($key > 0) {
            $result = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php

  $a = array(3,4,7);
  $b = array(2,4,7);

  for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
 {
      if($a[$i] > $b[$i]
       echo true;
 }

 ?>
```

will give true if a is greater.

Comment: `break` cycle will be a good way if just one difference found.